# Как получить данные в JSON без jQuery ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Как получить данные с сервера в формате JSON без использования ajax в jQuery?

Сейчас код выглядит так:

```
function options() { 
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "" + HOST + "options/",
        data: "id=" + window.ProjectId + "",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.status == 1) {
                init(); 
            }               
        }
    });             
}
```

Comment: Смотрите в  сторону JSONP: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение было найдено самостоятельно

```
var options;    

function options() {

        var url = ''+HOST+'api/options/?id_project=' + window.ProjectId + '&hash_person=' + hash_person + '';

        var XHR = ("onload" in new XMLHttpRequest()) ? XMLHttpRequest : XDomainRequest;

        var xhr = new XHR();

        xhr.open('GET', url, true);

        xhr.onload = function() {
            options = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        }

        xhr.onerror = function() {
            // alert( 'Ошибка ' + this.status );
            //console.log( 'Ошибка ' + this.status);
        }

        xhr.send();
    }
```

Вот и все что надо было сделать =)

Comment: И с чего же это без использования ajax, если это именно он и есть?

Comment: `var XHR = ("onload" in new XMLHttpRequest()) ? XMLHttpRequest : XDomainRequest;` - во-первых, жуть, во-вторых, что-то сомневаюсь, чтобы оно работало для второго варианта.

Comment: Вы как раз и используете AJAX, разве что без jQuery. ( см. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX ). А раз так, то формально, ваш ответ **не является** ответом на вопрос!

Comment: мне надо было чтобы он работал без jQuery по сути, я не знал изначально как написать вопрос.

Comment: @qwertiy если что это почти по учебнику!

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev, либо проблема в этом "почти", либо учебник какой-то не такой...

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, я отредактировал вопрос.

Comment: @Qwertiy, спасибо, убрал свои минусы как с вопроса так и с ответа.

Comment: @Qwertiy, учебник https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev, порылся. Похоже, [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2) опять неправ. Код рабочий, хотя мне он и не нравится. Но есть вероятность, что более нормальная проверка в IE не взлетит.

Comment: а как лучше сделать его?

Comment: @Qwertiy, это хак, скорее, смотри [ссылку](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest#ie8-9-xdomainrequest). Для старых IE. Ничего плохого в строчке нет.

Answer (score 2):

Через [JSONP](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-jsonp):

```
function options(projectId, dataType, callbackFuncName) {
  var 
    url = HOST + 'options/?id=' + projectId + '&dataType=' + 
            dataType + '&callbackFuncName=' + callbackFuncName,
    scriptEl = document.createElement('script');

  scriptEl.src = url;
  document.head.appendChild(scriptEl);
}

callbackFunc(data) {
  // Обработка
}

options(window.ProjectId, 'jsonp', 'callbackFunc');
```

На стороне сервера мы должны отдать следующее:

```
callbackFuncName({
  //json
});
```

Где `callbackFuncName` - это полученное имя функции - обработчика

Comment: у меня идет обращение к php  файлу там json отдает так $json_output = array('succes'=>1, 'mes' => '...'); echo json_encode($json_output); Как мне то что получится засунуть в callbackFuncName({  //jso }); если я правильно вас понял

Comment: `echo $_GET['callbackFuncName '] . '(' . json_encode($json_output) . ');';` Если я правильно помню как это в php делается.

Comment: сделал так `options(window.ProjectId, hash_person, 'jsonp', 'callbackFunc');function options(projectId, hp, dataType, callbackFuncName) {
  var 
    url = HOST + 'api/options/?id=' + projectId + '&hash_person=' + hp + '&dataType=' + dataType + '&callbackFuncName=' + callbackFuncName,
    scriptEl = document.createElement('script');
 scriptEl.src = url;
 document.head.appendChild(scriptEl);
}

callbackFunc(data) {
 if(data.status == 1){
  init(); 
 }    

}`